# PHP library used with C#

Tags: php

Is there a library I can use my C# (my option because this language is feasible-useable in most platforms; it truly outperforms C++ and Java, up to 85-90% : just personal % but self reliable) with PHP ? I am new to PHP, just don't know what to do with it until I'm commanded.

Sorry, i mean to setups to display in browsers, and to use in database,.

Comment: C# absolutely doesn't outperform C++.

Comment: C# definitely better than C++

Comment: It's a multiproblem solver. C++ is a language for promotion of bad habits of use (ie global hooks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean integrating C# libraries with PHP, yes, you can.

PHP happens to have a rarely-used COM library. I'm fairly sure it's what you're looking for.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php

However, consider simply learning either ASP.NET (C#-like) or PHP itself. Combining two languages is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Sorry I mean PHP that helps, not ASP that doesn't especially in case, I work as a web designer to build forum sites. PHP seems more powerful.

Comment: @Tom 10 years as a PHP dev and I never knew about that COM library - thanks for the tip!

Comment: Based on much experience porting and upgrading legacy projects in a wide range of languages, I agree with Tom's statement "Combining two languages is almost never a good idea.". Except in an environment that is designed to combine languages (in .Net, mixing VB and C# is straightforward; I do it daily), only combine two languages if there is no other way to solve your problem. One exception: it is useful to use a language "closer to the metal" for performance or OS stuff such as drivers, plus a "friendlier" language for other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

CAVEAT: I have not used PeachPie or Phalanger at all.

Depending on your requirements, one approach is to bring PHP into the .NET environment.

See [PeachPie](https://www.peachpie.io/).
PeachPie is based on [Phalanger compiler](https://github.com/devsense/phalanger/)

NOTE: As in all attempts to combine different technologies, expect to have to learn some of *both* environments, to be productive. And expect to bump into annoying problems, limitations, and bugs that wouldn't be an issue if only using one of the two.

Also consider: when you encounter a problem, it may be harder to find a solution:
Many people use php. Many people use c#. Only a tiny fraction of those people try to combine the two.